# Multer-s3 Uploading empty files on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, fabricjs, multer-s3

I'm using angular and multer-s3 to upload files from an angular app to a node server. Everything works well on the desktop but for some reason when trying to upload the photo via my iPhone 7 the uploaded file is corrupt. I'm using the same image and running through the same flow on both devices but getting different results so I'm assuming its because of mobile?

Here's the alert I get when trying to open the S3 file on the mobile

```
The file “1519398514215-test.png” could not be opened because it is empty.
```

Here's my code

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var path = require('path');
var path3 = path.join(__dirname, "../config/config-aws.json");
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var request = require('request');

aws.config.loadFromPath(path3);
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var fileName = '';
var uploadM = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'XXXX',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname + '.png'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      fileName =  Date.now().toString() + "-" + file.originalname + '.png' ;
      cb(null, fileName)
    }
  })
});



router.post('/', uploadM.array('photos', 3), function(req,res) {
  if (res.error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Error",
      error: res.error
    });
  }
  const url = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXX/' + fileName;
  return res.status(200).json({
    fileName: url
  });
});
```

And here's my client-side

```
sendImage() {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();

  this.removeObjectFromCanvas('polygon');


  if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
    alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
  } else {
    // window.open(this.canvas.toDataURL('png'));
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = this.canvas.toDataURL('png');



        const blob = this.dataURItoBlob(image.src);

        const file = new File([blob], 'test.png');


        formData.append('photos', file, 'test');



        this.postFile(formData);
      }


    }

    postFile(file) {
      this.fileService.post(file)
      .subscribe(data => {

      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

UPDATE **********

So found out you can debug on mobile. It looks like the buffer I am sending has data in it. My first thought was the buffer was not sending.

[image]

**** Update
Still can't figure this out. I've done some research and its possible it has something to do with formData and append? But as you can see by the image above both seem to be fine. Will continue to research ...

***** UPDATE
Definitely uploading empty files. But its only on mobile?

[image]

Also, I checked the formData prior to sending to the node server, seems to have the correct data in it.

*** UPDATE

Ok, even weirder experience. It seems multer-s3 is uploading empty files but when I take the file on the server-side and return it to the client-side, then read that file and display it, the image is displayed perfectly. So the formData is not the issue, it's something with multer-s3 I'm assuming?

****UPDATE
I forgot to mention I am using fabricjs and getting the image from the canvas. I read in some places there may be an issue there but like I said above when I send the file to the server and send it back to the client, after reading the file it displays the image perfectly.

****Update
I tried adding contentType to the multer method and now I'm receiving a 503 service unavailable error when running on mobile only. For desktop it is fine.

```
aws.config.loadFromPath(path3);
var file1;
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var fileName = '';
var uploadM = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'rent-z',
    acl: 'public-read',
    contentType: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'image/png');
    },
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log(file);
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      fileName =  Date.now().toString() + "-" + file.originalname;
      file1 = file;
      cb(null, fileName)
    }
  })
}).array('photos', 1);



router.post('/', function(req,res) {
  uploadM(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "Error uploading to multer",
        error: err
      });
    }
  console.log('worked');

  if (res.error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Error",
      error: res.error
    });
  }
  // fs.readFile(req.body, function (err, data) { 
  const url = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rent-z/' + fileName;
  return res.status(200).json({
    fileName: url
  });
  // });
  })

});
```

I even tried running multer-s3's automatic find mime-type function and that did give the same result

**** Day 4

It's been 96 hours since I started debugging this problem. No progress has been made. Still trying to figure out why its working on desktop and not mobile. For anyone looking for a quick summary of behavior:

1. User uploads image on the desktop
2. User places image on canvas
3. Use scales image
4. User presses sendImage
5. This converts the image to dataUri then blob
6. This blob is added to a file which is appended to formData
7. This formData is sent to a nodejs server where multer-s3 middleware 
   uploads the file to s3 successfully
8. User tries on mobile
9. Fails at step 7. The file is uploaded but is empty.

Let me know if anyone has any ideas on how to continue.

Comment: Does anyone know anywhere I could be checking? Ive tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Wild guess (don’t even know what Multer is): set correct `Content-Type`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/200603

Comment: Thanks for the tip and actually trying! Unfortunately, I tried setting the contentType in multer-s3 and same issue, works on desktop but not on mobile .. Although, now Im getting a 503 on mobile so Im checking into that error.

Comment: I can't help with the code, but uploadcare and filestack both have free tiers. Passing these types of issues off to an api/service can save a lot of headache.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @kayakinKoder I'm checking into uploadcare right now as it seems to fit our needs best. Definitely a viable option!

Comment: Uploadcare does have direct to S3 uploads, it's not advertised just yet :)

Comment: @DmitryMukhin good to hear, removed my comment

Comment: are you sure the mobile produces a good file? for debugging sake, can you check that the image taken from the mobile canvas is good?

Comment: What I've done to check is send the file through the process and have my nodejs server return that same file after its upload to S3 and then reading and displaying the file in html. It returns the full image ...

Comment: Take me the node and angular versions.

Comment: Node 8.9.1 and Angular 5.2.2

Comment: @JonathanCorrin, can you create minimal reproducible git repo? This would help other debug the issue instead of just comment and give directions

Answer (score 5):

I'll make this an "official" answer since this may work for your needs. Anytime I have an intricate issue like this, my first thought is often "I wonder if there is an API/SaaS/service out there that can abstract this for me." As you've found, file uploads are tricky, particularly when you start throwing in the myriad devices we have to deal with these days.

I won't mention any particular services, but googling "file upload saas" will generally get you the top industry players. For $25 - $50/month you can abstract file uploads to a very simple api call. Not only do you get time savings now, but (assuming you choose a solid provider) you get no more headaches regarding file uploads in the future. It's the SaaS's job to make sure file uploads work on a million different devices; it's the SaaS's job to make sure S3 integration works, even when S3's api changes; it's the SaaS's job to make sure the user sees a nice friendly message if their upload fails for some reason, etc. I get to spend my time building features for our app instead of worrying about whether or not file uploads work on the iPhone 47.

"But then I'm tied to a SaaS, and live at the whim of their prices and feature set" Ah, but you can minimize that problem. For many services we use, I like to make a wrapper/interface/whatever you'd like to call it. In the case of file uploads, I made an ES6 module: `fileUploads.js`

In this module, I have a method `upload`. What does this method do? It simply implements and abstracts the API of [fileupload SaaS X]. If in the future we want, or need, to change from SaaS X to SaaS Y, I only have to change one thing in our entire app: my `fileUpload.js` module.

Comment: I'm reaching out to few Saas companies. Once I integrate one and it solves my problem (today or tomorrow) I will mark as correct!

Comment: @JonathanCorrin thanks, no worries, someone may come along and figure out what the issue is with your code. Still, I'd think: what about 2 months from now when a customer tells me they can't upload files on their blackberry. Do I want to spend my time trying to debug that myself, or submit a ticket to [SaaS company X] and let them figure it out? The later, for sure.